# Could a callable cloud function that delete users be abused so it can delete users by only id?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a callable cloud function on the frontend, that gets a sub-user id from front-end pass it to the cloud function, and then the cloud function delete that user and also deletes his doc from the collection...

my question is could someone get the id of some user and use that function and start popping requests using this function to delete users left and right ?

it make sense that this could function won't follow any rules, so I consider this to be a major security risk if implemented in the wrong way any idea how to improve security on this and guard against any abuse attempts.

Front end callable function

```js
const functions = getFunctions();
const deleteClient = httpsCallable(functions, 'deleteClient');
      
deleteClient({ uid: 'clientId' })
     .then((result: any) => {
      // Read result of the Cloud Function.
      /** @type {any} */
      //  const data = result.data;
      // const sanitizedMessage = data.text;
      console.log(result);
     })
     .catch((err: any) => {
     alert(err);
   });
```

Cloud Function

```js
export const deleteClient = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  admin
    .auth()
    .deleteUser(data.uid)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Successfully deleted user');
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
    });

  db.collection('ClientsData').doc(data.uid).delete();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed sounds like you created a security risk, and is also precisely why Firebase Authentication only allows deleting the currently signed-in user in its client-side SDKs.

You'll have to implement some sort of authorization scheme in your Cloud Functions code. This takes a two step process:

1. Pass the identity of the signed-in user making the call from the client to the server, and use it there to establish who is making the call. Since you're using Callable Cloud Functions, this is already done for you and the user is available in the `context.auth` variable in your Cloud Functions code.
2. Determine whether the user is authorized to perform the operation. This is typically done by having a list of authorized users, and then checking of the `context.auth.uid` who made the call is in that list. The list could be stored in your database too of course, so that you can update it without making changes to the code.

Comment: what I did is I referenced the admin in the doc of the sub-user which is not mutable by all means... and now I am tiring to check if the user who is trying to make the delete is the same one that is referenced inside of the doc..... can I delete users by batch or just singular  ?

Comment: The documentation is your friend here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_multiple_users